# Batch size and weight updates

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science-experience

Could you clarify this question.

I have Epoch of 1000 and Batch size 100. (Then 1 epoch will be 10 batch sizes).

May I know when will the weights get updated. WIll it update for every batch size
or at the end of every epoch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Editing)
This will update the weights at end of every epoch.

For details, follow this answer:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117919/what-are-the-differences-between-epoch-batch-and-minibatch